Git Merge Request to Feature Branch Includes Many Old and Unrelated Changes
Currently I have a branch, called branchA, and I wish to push my changes to another branch, called featureBranch, which was based off master.
BranchA is being kept up to date with master, whereas featureBranch has not.
When creating a merge request from branchA to featureBranch, I can see my merge request contains many changes unrelated to the actual changes I've made, this is due to featureBranch being updated when compared to master. How can I get featureBranch up to date with master so that my merge request only contains the changes I've made?
In other words, currently, my merge request has hundreds of files changed and thousands of new lines, however I would like it to only show the few couple of changes from my actual work, how could this be achieved?

Can we see the relevant parts of git log --graph --decorate --all --oneline? This will show your true history of master, BranchA, featureBranch. Please be sure to sanitize the commit logs so you're not posting private information.

Just merge master into featureBranch, either manually or with an MR. After that, the MR from branchA to featureBranch should automatically update to only show the new changes on branchA.

What does this mean: "BranchA is being kept up to date with master". How do you keep BranchA up-to-date?

As I understand, you could try rebase instead of merge. Just instead of command merge - type rebase
From featureBranch type :git rebase master
